# History.js for HTML5 - Hack Needed to Not Break IE7

Tags: history.js

My goal is to support AJAX history for HTML5 browsers only.  However, I would like my site to work with HTML4 browsers, but without AJAX history.

Many of the History.js examples include the following check before performing any operations:

```
if (!History.enabled) {
    // History.js is disabled for this browser.
    // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
    return false;
}
```

This would seem to work except for the fact that older browser such as IE7 do not support native JSON and the History.js plugin requires `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`.

The suggested solution is to include json2.js ([link](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/issues/105)).  This seems kind of strange to me since HTML5 browsers that support `pushState()` and `popState()` should also support native JSON.  Also, I do not want to include yet another library that I do not really need.  My solution is to conditionally include History.js as follows:

```
var nativeJSON = (typeof JSON === 'object') && (typeof JSON.parse === 'function') && (typeof JSON.stringify === 'function');
if (nativeJSON) {
    /// Include contents of: balupton-history.js-e84ad00\scripts\bundled\html5\jquery.history.js
} else {
    window.History = { enabled: false };
}
```

This seems to work, but feels like a hack.  Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT: 7/31/2012**

If I do not include history.html4.js it still gives me an error on IE7.  It appears that including json2.js is simply a requirement of this plugin at the moment.  An improvement could probably be made to silently check for JSON support and disable the plugin if there is none, but for now I have a workaround.  Here is a snippit from History.js:

```
/**
 * History.js Core
 * @author Benjamin Arthur Lupton <contact@balupton.com>
 * @copyright 2010-2011 Benjamin Arthur Lupton <contact@balupton.com>
 * @license New BSD License <http://creativecommons.org/licenses/BSD/>
 */

(function(window,undefined){
    "use strict";

    // ========================================================================
    // Initialise

    // Localise Globals
    var
        console = window.console||undefined, // Prevent a JSLint complain
        document = window.document, // Make sure we are using the correct document
        navigator = window.navigator, // Make sure we are using the correct navigator
        sessionStorage = window.sessionStorage||false, // sessionStorage
        setTimeout = window.setTimeout,
        clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout,
        setInterval = window.setInterval,
        clearInterval = window.clearInterval,
        JSON = window.JSON,
        alert = window.alert,
        History = window.History = window.History||{}, // Public History Object
        history = window.history; // Old History Object

    // MooTools Compatibility
    JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify||JSON.encode;
    JSON.parse = JSON.parse||JSON.decode;
```

If window.JSON is undefined, referencing window.JSON.stringify will simply cause an error.

Comment: What happens if you don't include history.html4? From the source, it looks like it will just silently not initialize...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it for my case.  I wanted to use public CDNs when possible and combine all other JS code for my site into a single include file.  Here is what the code looks like.

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <!-- JS Files Hosted on CDN(s) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <!-- Combined Custom JS File -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The single JS include file combines all needed plugins and any custom code needed to run the site.

**Site.js**

```
// History.js plugin
var nativeJSON = (typeof JSON === 'object') && (typeof JSON.parse === 'function') && (typeof JSON.stringify === 'function');
if (nativeJSON) {
    // contents of browserstate-history.js-e84ad00\scripts\bundled\html5\jquery.history.js
} else {
    window.History = { enabled: false };
}

/*
Watermark v3.1.3 (March 22, 2011) plugin for jQuery
http://jquery-watermark.googlecode.com/
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Todd Northrop
http://www.speednet.biz/
Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
*/
// contents of jquery.watermark.min.js


// INCLUDE more plugins here


// Custom JS Code here
```

Chances are I will want to send down at least some custom JS code and this allows me to send it all in 1 payload.  From what I understand it is good practice to [combine resource files](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

**EDIT: 2013-06-25**

In subsequent projects I have simply included a minified version of `json2.js` into my combined JS file.  Using Google's [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) you can get it down to about 3K (before HTTP compression) which seems acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me in IE7 with no errors:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Tell us whether History is enabled
        var alertHistory = function() {
            alert(History.enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled');
        }

        var nativeJSON = (typeof JSON === 'object') && (typeof JSON.parse === 'function') && (typeof JSON.stringify === 'function');
        if (nativeJSON) {
            // Native JSON is present, add History.js
            var historyJs = document.createElement('script');
            historyJs.type = 'text/javascript';
            historyJs.src = 'https://raw.github.com/browserstate/history.js/master/scripts/bundled/html5/jquery.history.js';
            historyJs.onload = alertHistory;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(historyJs);
        } else {
            window.History = { enabled: false };
            alertHistory();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see how this would work, but we are sort of doing the same thing.  The difference is that you are loading the History.js library via a 2nd HTTP request and I am sending both the library and JSON test in a single payload.

Comment: @dana yes I agree. It's not ideal, but it *does* get around the error IE7 was throwing. If you put it inside a `document ready` event then it will make your page appear to load more quickly as well, which could be a bonus for non IE7 visitors.