# IE7 Object Expected on .post() json return

Tags: json, internet-explorer

I'm having a problem on ie7 with my json return. I can't seem to find what's wrong with it, that it would break ie. The line that comes out with an error is `var countries = JSON.parse(data);`

```
["Argentina","Australia","Brazil","China","Colombia","Czech Republic","Hong Kong SAR","India","Japan","Malaysia","Mexico","Peru","Russia","Singapore","South Africa","South Korea","Taiwan","Thailand","Turkey","United Kingdom","Vietnam"]
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: ie7? You still have to support ie7 from October 2006? Are you including [json2.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11549661/2970947)?

Comment: I haven't included that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Tried it, haven't solved the problem.

Comment: Not my first choice (or even second), but does a raw `eval` work?